# How To Find Out If Remote Image Exist in iphone?

Tags: iphone, image, url

I was googling but ddnt find any suitable answer

i have 5 URL, in each url there is an image,

but only 3 URL is opening, and remaining 2 are not opening when i put that url in browswser

The requested URL /uploads/ad_pictures/CrkahbML.jpg was not found on this server.

so how can i find out that is that a valid url in objective c

Please need your help

explain me with a simple example

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You can validate URL by using the following code

```
 - (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
     NSString *urlRegEx =
     @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
     NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
     return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code:

```
NSURL* imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:passingData.attachedImageString];
NSData* imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
if (image != NULL) {
    //There is an image 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find Valid image url using following

```
- (BOOL)isImageUrl:(NSString*)urls {
    NSArray *elements = @[@"http", @"."];
    for (NSString *element in elements) {
        if ([urls rangeOfString:element].location == NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    NSArray *possibleFiles = @[@"jpeg", @"png", @"jpg"];
    for (NSString *file in possibleFiles) {
        if ([urls rangeOfString:file].location != NSNotFound) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

just pass image url in method, if it returns true there is valid image...